# The reason of Compact algorithm called 'Compact'?

Tags: garbage-collection

As we know, the Compact algorithm also use copying to move the live objects
in a continuous memory space in order to eliminate the memory fragmentation. Why not consider the Compact algorithm as a type of Copying algorithm. Could any one tell me the reason of Compact algorithm called 'Compact'?

Comment: Think of *compact* as in *compress*. Like a trash compactor, that turns your kitchen garbage into a small block that can be easily disposed.

Comment: good illustration! Thank you

Comment: @Ken White Could you help me eliminate this confusion, thank you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820136/mark-compact-algorithm-vs-copying-algorithm-in-young-generation